# unable remove class inside form-control and add new class bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have table with two td's one select country option and another  input text.

```
    <tr>
      <td><select name="country" class='form-control country' id="country">
        <option value="">-select country-</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
        <option value="eng">England</option>
        <option value="nzl">New Zealand</option>
      </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='form-control country_name'></td>
    </tr>
    <p id="ppl"></p>
```

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jvk3/wbzasubL/1/

Based on the country change i need to remove text class and add new class. 
For example I have change country to usa  I need remove  text class of country_name with usa_country, if he change country to eng i need remove country_name to eng_country

Here is my jquery code.

```
    $(".country").on('change', function(){
  var cty_name = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('td.country_name').removeClass('coutry_name')
    .addClass(çty_name+'_counrty')
    })
```

I have tried many ways but i didn't success. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

`this` referes to `.country` which is not a sibling of `.country_name` element (your selector is also wrong) thus [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will never work.

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up ancestor `TD` element and then use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to target immediately following sibling `TD`, afterwards use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target `INPUT` element.

```
 $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').removeClass('coutry_name').addClass(çty_name+'_counrty');
```

OR,

If you have single input, travese up to `TR`, then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('input').removeClass('coutry_name').addClass(çty_name+'_counrty');
```